# Visual Studio is saying my INCLUDE statement is undefined and I cannot determine why

Tags: assembly, x86, include

At the moment I am trying to write a very simple x86 assembly language program:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

.code
main PROC
    mov eax,5
    call writeInt

exit

main ENDP
END main
```

However, the INCLUDE statement is underlined and when I hover over it, it says:

```
Error: identifier "INCLUDE" is undefined
```

I have the Irvine library downloaded correctly according to my professor and numerous online tutorials and this program itself is from an online tutorial:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isS432XiT58
```

There is also no error in the output tool window when I build the program, but here is everything in the output window nonetheless:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication165, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling main.asm...
1>  LINK : C:\Users\Collin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication165\Debug\ConsoleApplication165.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>  ConsoleApplication165.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Collin\documents\visual studio     2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication165\Debug\ConsoleApplication165.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This really comes from trying to solve a related problem in a homework assignment, but I have been unable to solve that and I believe that this is the source. Anyone have any ideas why I am getting the undefined identifier error above?

Comment: Probably because you're not assembling it with MASM but compiling it with the C++ or some other Visual Studio language compiler.

Comment: @RossRidge Very possible, though I selected the MASM customization file in build customizations. Do you know where that configuration setting might be located? I have otherwise tried to very carefully follow all instructions given to me by my teacher and presented online in order to code in assembly in Visual Studio properly.

Comment: Sorry, no clue. You might have to ask your teacher for assistance.

Comment: Does the file end with the `.asm` extension? Remove the file from the solution and re-add it.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message that you get in the "Output" tool window? Copy and paste that into your question, please. (Not what IntelliSense gives you.) That will have an error code associated with it, which will tell us which compiler you're actually using to try and compile the code.

Comment: @RossRidge I have asked my teacher for assistance, he didn't have any advice to give me. This is for an online course across the country so I can't exactly take the problem to him. But thank you for taking a look at my question!

Comment: @CodyGray There is no error message in the "Output" tool window, but I can post everything that is in there for whatever assistance it might provide.

Comment: Okay, then there is no error. Everything assembled correctly. You can see that from the very last line: `Build: 1 succeeded`. It assembled and linked correctly, and your EXE is here: `C:\Users\Collin\documents\visual studio     2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication165\Debug\ConsoleApplication165.exe`. This "error" you're seeing about `INCLUDE` is almost certainly due to IntelliSense, which is a real-time syntax checker designed to work with C and C++. It doesn't understand assembly language code, so it's going to be completely unhelpful to you and you can just ignore it.

Comment: @CodyGray I am afraid the program doesn't run. If I just ignore it then the program doesn't run and I get a pop-up message saying that VS is unable to run my program, "Unable to run 'C:\.....'". I am open to the idea that the cause is something else, but I am unsure what it might be.

Comment: Honestly, that makes no sense. You can see clearly in the Output window that the build is completing successfully, *and* it's creating an EXE in the path that I quoted. If you navigate to that path and double-click on the EXE, what happens? If you try running that EXE from a command line prompt, what happens? The only thing I can think of is that your virus scanner may be causing problems. Try disabling it for your "\Projects" sub-directory, or turning it off altogether.

Comment: I would agree that it seems very odd. If I go to the indicated file path it is there about half the time. If I try and run the executable, either from a windows explorer or from the command prompt, It will say something along the lines of Access Denied, Cannot Find File, etc.. I have tried turning off my anti-virus, but I will try that again as I have most definitely had that problem in the past. I also took my computer into a Microsoft store the other day and received some assistance. I had to do numerous updates/installs. I don't know if they'll help, but I'll know when I get home today.

Comment: Updates from Microsoft store didn't help, the intellisense message around my INCLUDE statement is gone, but I am still getting the "Unable to run" error.